# page loader not working how do that

Tags: jquery, loader

page loader not show in search data in before load to list.
 $("#loader").css("display", "none"); not show to loader and  $("#loader").css("display", "Block"); after all data load and loader still show there

```
<body onload="myloaderFunction()">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div class="MainWin">
    </div>
    </body>
```

jquery:

```
function SearchForResult(ResultElement, searchType) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        $("#loader").css("display", "none");
        switch (searchType.toLowerCase()) {
            case "repsearch":
                sysmClicked();
                break;

            default:
                //sysmClicked();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

style:

```css
#loader {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    background-image: url('../../assets/images/icons/loader.gif');
}
```

Comment: Where is `myLoaderFunction()` defined? The only function you have defined (in the snippet you provided) is `SearchForResult`

Comment: You have an extra closing `div` tag in that first block of HTML. Did you leave anything out?

Comment: both are define in layout page